# How to prevent changes to a prototype?

Tags: javascript, object-create

In this code, the prototype can still change.

How I can prevent changes to the prototype?

```
var a = {a:1}
var b={b:1}
var c = Object.create(a)
Object.getPrototypeOf(c) //a
c.__proto__ = b;
Object.getPrototypeOf(c) //b
var d = Object.create(null)
Object.getPrototypeOf(d) //null
d.__proto__ = b;
Object.getPrototypeOf(d) //null
```

Comment: A prototype is just an object like every other one, meaning that you can freeze/seal it.

Comment: `__proto__` is deprecated. Use `Object.setPrototypeOf` if you have to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How I can prevent changes to the prototype?

I assume you are not talking about mutating the prototype object itself, but overwriting the prototype of an existing object.

You can use [`Object.preventExtensions()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions) to prevent that:

```js
var a = {a:1}
var b = {b:1}
var c = Object.create(a)
Object.preventExtensions(c) 
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(c)) //a
c.__proto__ = b; // Error
```

But that also means you cannot *add* any new properties to it. You could also use [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) or [`Object.seal()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) depending on your needs, which restrict modifications to the object even more.

There are no other ways though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can ,use Object.freeze.

Object.freeze() method freezes an object: that is, prevents new properties from being added to it; prevents existing properties from being removed; and prevents existing properties, or their enumerability, configurability, or writability, from being changed. In essence the object is made effectively immutable. The method returns the object being frozen.

See this [freeze reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

check this snippet

```js
var a = {a:1}
var b={b:1}
var c = Object.create(a)
Object.getPrototypeOf(c) //a
Object.freeze(c);
c.__proto__ = b;//throws error now
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(c)) //a
var d = Object.create(null)
Object.getPrototypeOf(d) //null
d.__proto__ = b;
Object.getPrototypeOf(d) //null
```

Hope this helps